# Code blocks always runs main.cpp in a project

Tags: c++, ide, codeblocks

I have code blocks 17and i created a new project.

1. Clicked create new project

2.Console application

3.C++

4.Gave it a name and stored it in an empty folder

5.Created new file inside the project and wrote some code.

When i build, it builds without errors. When i run it, It always runs main.cpp by default. How do i execute other files without having to run main.cpp everytime.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't run main.cpp - it runs the main() function, which might be in any named .cpp file - a file with the name main.cpp is not special as far as Code::Blocks, or C++ in general, is concerned. But a Code::Blocks project can only have one main() function.

Comment: Hi, Neil. This is my second question you are answering, thanks for helping. So what exactly should i do right now?

Comment: Create separate projects.

Comment: @AryanParekh inside the main function, write the code You want to execute.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, you could delete the main.cpp file from the project or just add the `int main()` function into the file that you want and remove the one in main.cpp

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a file before you run it so insted of giving only run give build&run option.